# Disable Close of Application (via Tasklist) while modal dialog is open

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

Since Windows 7 it is possible to close my application via Tasklist -> close even when a modal dialog is on the screen. 
In earlier Versions of Windows the "close" button in the task line of the desktop is disabled as are all parent windows of the dialog in my application. 
In Win7 (and above) the parent windows of the dialog are still disabled, but not the close() item in the taskbar. 
Such a scenario (close of while while modal dialog is on the screen) yields a crash of my application. 
(Note: we are talking about >>100 dialogs, and >>100 .exe files. )
i am even happy with a completly removing this close item in the taskbar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Diagnosing the error and fixing it is not an option?

Comment: As IInspectable says, fixing your application is the obvious solution.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Instead of fixing a bug in your code, you want to prevent users from shutting down _your_ software on _their_ system? You even suggest removing a crucial control from Windows itself?

Answer (score 2):

Closing an application is signaled with the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx) with a parameter of `SC_CLOSE`. If you put in a message handler you can intercept the request and do whatever you want.

Be aware of two things: applications that don't close when you want them to are very frustrating for a user, and it's always possible to force-close an application via the Task Manager.